# DTraceAsmProfiler of JMH fails with '[sudo: a password is required' on Mac

Tags: profiler, jmh, dtrace

I'm running a benchmark from IDEA on MacOS with `DTraceAsmProfiler` and it fails with this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.openjdk.jmh.runner.ProfilersFailedException: Profilers failed to initialize, exiting.
    at org.openjdk.jmh.runner.Runner.internalRun(Runner.java:228)
    at org.openjdk.jmh.runner.Runner.run(Runner.java:209)
    at com.tsypanov.benchmark.BenchmarkRunner.main(BenchmarkRunner.java:45)
Caused by: org.openjdk.jmh.profile.ProfilerException: [sudo: a password is required
]
    at org.openjdk.jmh.profile.DTraceAsmProfiler.<init>(DTraceAsmProfiler.java:69)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at org.openjdk.jmh.profile.ProfilerFactory.instantiate(ProfilerFactory.java:82)
    at org.openjdk.jmh.profile.ProfilerFactory.getProfiler(ProfilerFactory.java:77)
    at org.openjdk.jmh.profile.ProfilerFactory.getProfilerOrException(ProfilerFactory.java:37)
    at org.openjdk.jmh.runner.Runner.internalRun(Runner.java:225)
    ... 2 more
```

My code:

```java
public class BenchmarkRunner {

  public static void main(String[] args) throws RunnerException {
    Options opt = new OptionsBuilder()
            .include(CRHMBenchmark.class.getSimpleName())
            .warmupIterations(10)
            .warmupTime(TimeValue.seconds(1))
            .measurementIterations(10)
            .measurementTime(TimeValue.seconds(1))
            .addProfiler(DTraceAsmProfiler.class)
            .forks(5)
            .build();

    new Runner(opt).run();
  }
}
```

Also I've tried to run it from terminal and got the same error:

```sh
% java -jar target/benchmarks.jar CRHMBenchmark -f 2 -w 1s -r 1s -prof dtraceasm
Profilers failed to initialize, exiting.
[sudo: a password is required
]
```

Has someone faced it before?

Comment: Have you tried to run it with elevated privileges (where `sudo` does not require a password)?

Comment: I'm trying 
```shell
stsypanov@MBP-SERGEYT assembly-profiling-and-all-all-all % sudo "/usr/bin/java" -jar target/benchmarks.jar CRHMBenchmark -f 2 -w 1s -r 1s -prof dtraceasm
The operation couldn’t be completed. Unable to locate a Java Runtime.
Please visit http://www.java.com for information on installing Java.
```
but it doesn't help either

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I've found the solution:

```sh
sudo "/Users/stsypanov/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/openjdk-17.0.1/Contents/Home/bin/java" -jar target/benchmarks.jar CRHMBenchmark -f 1 -w 1s -r 1s -prof dtraceasm -jvmArgsAppend "-XX:+UnlockDiagnosticVMOptions -XX:+PrintAssembly"
```

Comment: do you get any meaningful output btw? Some [time back](https://mail.openjdk.java.net/pipermail/jmh-dev/2020-February/002922.html) I have tried to play with this one too, but I gave up, eventually.

Comment: On jdk17 I got this:
```
 43,04%    0x000000011cc129e8: ;*getfield references {reexecute=0 rethrow=0 return_oop=0}
                               ; - org.springframework.util.ConcurrentReferenceHashMap$Segment::&lt;init&gt;@48 (line 488)
                               ; - org.springframework.util.ConcurrentReferenceHashMap::&lt;init&gt;@141 (line 184)
 43,04%    0x000000011cc129e8: 458b 5620 
  1,30%    0x000000011cc129ec: ; implicit exception: dispatches to 0x000000011cc1369c
```
To see actual asm I think I need to configure `hprof`, see https://habr.com/ru/post/542148/

Comment: thank you, I will take a look. Congrats on yet another awesome prrsentation, watched it today, very good, as usual!